# How can I update Gtk.ListBox dynamically?

Tags: listbox, gtk, vala

So I have a listbox:

```cs
var listbox = new Gtk.ListBox();

var l = new Watcher.ListItem.NewItem("title","subtitle", "etc");
listbox.insert(l, 0);
```

"l" is basically a *Gtk.ListBoxRow* with formated labels and stuff.

I added a button with label "New" which purpose is to add new items into the ListBox.

```cs
int i = 1;
back_new.clicked.connect( ()=>{
    l = new Watcher.ListItem.NewItem("title2", "subtitle2", "etc2");
    listbox.insert(l, i);
    i++;
});
```

The problem is if I check  with "*listbox.get_row_at_index(2)*" it shows that there is something in the listbox so something happens but the listbox in the gui is not updated.

Full code is here if needed: 
http://pastebin.com/u/Levike

Comment: Please include the code that creates the ListBoxRow and the widgets inside it. My guess is still that some of them are not visible (GTK+ unfortunately defaults to not visible for all new widgets).

Comment: inserting the first element (index: 0) is okay. So if I run the program I can see one element but when I click on the "back_new" button it doesn't add the second.(I mean it doesn't show up). I even tried creating a simple listboxrow element with only one label. No luck

Comment: but here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/u/Levike Listitem.vala is what you asked for @jku

Comment: I don't see the code I mentioned. In any case questions should be self contained: please consider adding a [small and self-contained](http://sscce.org) example in to the question: your chances of getting a useful answer will improve greatly.

Comment: "GTK+ unfortunately defaults to not visible for all new widgets". Can you tell me how to change it to show them? Sorry but You saw my previus question and my friend who dont know anything about vala or listbox knew what s my problem without my explanation. I don't want to flame or anything and thank you for your time but I can't ask this question easier. Reading @luciomrx answers maybe I have a bug. It should update the gui but for some reason it does not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

listbox.show_all() fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In other languages using gtk, I would do a l.show() to make sure the item becomes visible.
Perhaps the same here ?

Comment: didn't work. There is a filter func but I dont know how to use it.
http://references.valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ListBox.set_filter_func
And I don't even know if it's solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would assume a Gtk.ListBoxRow is like iter in Gtk.TreeModel even though it's a Gtk.Container. You can skip adding a widget into ListBoxRow (straight to ListBox), and it will automatically a ListBoxRow for you whether you like it or not. Maybe it's a bug (maybe...), maybe the devs should implement a model with Gtk.ListBox, but for now, just use Gtk.Container.add () everytime you want to append something inside Gtk.ListBox. In your code:

```
int i = 1;
back_new.clicked.connect( ()=>{
l = new Watcher.ListItem.NewItem("title2", "subtitle2", "etc2");
listbox.insert(l, i);
i++;
});
# change to listbox.add (the widget...not the listboxrow widget) and it will show
```

the thing about Gtk.ListBox, it is a container where you can filter and sort the children inside, also to "stuffed" complicated list's children easier (Gtk.TreeView only uses Gtk.CellRenderer ).

If you do not want that, i don't think you should use it, or not until next release.

Comment: Tried that too. listbox.add(new Gtk.Labe("asd"). Nothing changed in the ui. Are you suggesting that I should use Gtk.TreeView? I need at least 4 labels and an icon for a list item.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me. Anyway, yeah use Gtk.TreeView with 5 columns. 4 of them using Gtk.CellRendererText and 1 of them use Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf. Create a ListStore model, and get it from there so you can change the contain of the list anytime and just refresh it by calling "set_model". And by the way, set Gtk.TreeView property "headers-visible" to False, and voila, you get a markup Gtk.ListBox

Comment: that is awesome, what app is that..btw it will take a bit of tinkering creating model like that..haven't done it before but i'm sure it can be done..i will try coding a draft to try looks like the first picture

Comment: App that I'm working on :) no name for it tho, just a mockup. There is the "full" code in the post. a link to pastebin

Answer (score 0):

listbox.show_all() fixes my issue too.

my code was:

fist remove all items from listbox:

```
for row in self.gruppi_rows:
     self.listboxGrp.remove(row)
```

then put some other objects in listbox, as following, but no content was  showed in the list box:

```
     row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
     self.count+=1
     cbutton=Gtk.CheckButton(name)
     flag1=self.radiobuttonSelectAll.get_active() 
     flag2=self.radiobuttonSelectNone.get_active() 
     box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=10)
     cbutton.set_active(flag1)
     box.pack_start(cbutton, True, True, 0)
     row.add(box)
     self.listboxGrp.add(row)
```

adding following line at the end fixes the problem:

```
     self.listboxGrp.show_all()
```